# Change the split symbol on currency filter AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, filter, currency

I'm using a custom filter that I found:

```
   app.filter('noFractionCurrency',
         [ '$filter', '$locale', function(filter, locale) {
    var currencyFilter = filter('currency');
    var formats = locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
      return function(amount, currencySymbol) {
       var value = currencyFilter(amount, currencySymbol);
       var sep = value.indexOf(formats.DECIMAL_SEP);
        if(amount >= 0) { 
         return value.substring(0, sep);
        }
      return value.substring(0, sep) + ')';
    };
 }]);
```

But this filter just remove decimal numbers but I want to replace the splitter  ',' for '.'

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I have a feeling there might be a better way for you to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

If I get you right, you just want to use different separators for currencies.
This can be accomplished by using an angular predefined localization that fits your needs.

You'd have to do something like this (where in the example "de-de" needs to be replaced by whichever you want):

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
….
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
….
</head>
</html>
```

The localization files are provided by angular. Have a look in the docs I posted on the top for more Information.